# Email Piping using google apps within WP Engine

Tags: email, smtp

I am working on a feature where I need to catch all the incoming emails or email piping. My site is hosted in WPEngine but they don't host emails. They have suggested third party mailing service like Google Apps, Mailchimp, Aweber, etc.

I have decided to use Google Apps for business but I am not sure it supports email piping since it needs server configuration.

Anyone has any experience with this setup? Please share you thoughts or suggestions. I've been searching all day but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do with incoming emails?

Comment: I need to fetch the message and add it to the comment section.